# Titanium.Platform.id contains UUID or UDID for Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

According to the appcelerator's doc :

```
Titanium.Platform.id : StringREADONLY
Applications's globally-unique ID (UUID).

On Android, this may be the UDID (unique device ID). For iOS, this is a unique identifier for this install of the application.

Previously on iOS this may have been a UDID, but access to this has been restricted by Apple.
```

On Android does it return UDID or any other unique identifier because docs says it may be UDID.

As well as for iOS only UUID is available, is it same as any one of the following CFUUID, NSUUID or Identifier for Vendor.

Answer (score 3):

For Android `Ti.Platform.id` uses `TiPlatformHelper.getInstance().getMobileId()` which it inherits from a closed source `APSAnalyticsHelper` helper for Appcelerator Analytics. I can't share the source, but its basically a UUID we generate and store in a persistent sqlite DB.

For iOS it uses [TiUtils.appIdentifier](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/bc85170157d3bebc5de1d61a9fe6e34bce84a8c9/iphone/Classes/TiUtils.m#L1796) which essentially does the exact same thing.

So, to answer your question: both use a generated and persistently stored UUID. It's just that the format of the UUIDs are different across both platform.

Answer (score 1):

I log the Ti.Platform.id and the results i get are the following

```
|Ti.Platform.id | Username | Login | Ti.Platform.name - Ti.Platform.version | Ti.Platform.manufacturer + " - " + Ti.Platform.model;

| Platform ID                          | User   | Login | OS                | Device          |
|--------------------------------------|--------|-------|-------------------|-----------------|
| 538B1B72-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-192A09BEF0CB | demoiOS| 1     | iPhone OS - 8.1.2 | apple - iPad3,4 |
| bb6bffffd1695d0d                     | demo   | 1     | android - 4.4.4   | Sony - D6503    |
```

I have redacted a part of the ID's though you should get the point.

And in their source code I can find only this:

titanium_mobile/android/modules/platform/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/platform/PlatformModule.java

```
@Kroll.method
    public String createUUID() {
        return TiPlatformHelper.getInstance().createUUID();
    }
```

Which is the java hook, but I cant find the TiPlatformHelper to give you the exact answer

You might want to check this code, though I cannot find the correct method
[Titanium GitHub project link](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/titanium/src/java/org/appcelerator/titanium/util/TiPlatformHelper.java)